# php mail() function

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am new at php coding and dont know much about networking (I started 2 weeks ago), so please bear with me.

1. Recently I came across the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.  First of all, I just wrote the simple code using [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) without any modifications in `php.ini` file, naturally it didnt work.  So I googled the cause; I found that for linux in [mail function] we have to type in `sendmail_path` the smtp server name.  I have an account at yahoo.com so I typed `smtp.mail.yahoo.com`, but this didn't seem to work.  So I again googled that and came to know that smtp server of your ISP is required there.  My program is a simple testing one and I would love to see the mail in the addresse's inbox as a result of php's code.
2. Also doesn't the apache server (which I use for responding to php code) have smtp support?  What is the thing stopping it from messaging?  If you feel I need to read please help me with a link.
3. Is there a difference between yahoo's/gmail's smtp and my isp's smtp, or is it that my isp's smtp communicates with yahoo's smtp to send mail (because though our isp change but we continue to send messages using same yahoo account)?

Comment: PHP just needs an SMTP server to send mail through.  It doesn't matter if it's your ISP's or Yahoo's or Google's (your ISP has nothing to do with Yahoo's SMTP server).  `sendmail_path` should be set to the `sendmail` executable on your server (if you don't know, don't touch this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You misread the information. The [sendmail_path](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) directive does not expect a server name, it expects the path of the sendmail binary. Under Linux, you can't use an external SMTP server with plain `mail()` function.
2. Apache is a web server. If offers HTTP but not any other service (such as SMTP or FTP). Perhaps you are confused with Microsoft IIS.
3. Not sure I understand the question but, nowadays, almost nobody allows to use his SMTP server to send third-party mail. If you want to send e-mail as `@yahoo.com` you'll have to use Yahoo's SMTP server.

Some additional hints:

- Linux servers normally have a local MTA (mail transport agent) installed so you don't have to deal with external SMTP services. It's not clear whether you tried sending e-mail before touching anything.
- If you want to send e-mail through Yahoo or Gmail or some similar service, you'd better use some third-party PHP library like PEAR::Mail, PHPMailer or Swift Mailer. PHP does not support e-mail authentication natively.

Comment: i did try to send email without any modifications but to no avail

Comment: is it like to send a mail from my machine i would have to use my isp's smtp server but to send it from yahoo i would have to use yahoo's smtp...and can i access yahoo's smtp server through code if i have an account on it

Comment: @SnuS - If you can send mail with Outlook or Thunderbird (I don't know if it's the case with Yahoo) you can send mail with PHP.

Comment: @alvaro...i think u didnt understand i was just asking that is it like when we send an email from our yahoo id by logging in at yahoo.com(the normal way) we use yahoo's smtp server....and if i put my isp's smtp address in sendmail_path (in php.ini) i will be using my isp's smtp server

Answer (score 2):

You should contact your ISP for your SMTP server name and credentials. Many SMTP servers require valid login credentials before sending message to avoid unauthorized use by spammers.

Apache can interact with a mail server such as Sendmail, but does not have built-in support.

Please see the [Sendmail website](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) for information about installing your own SMTP server, or install using the packages provided for your OS or distribution.

Comment: so is there no way(except using) in which i can send a mail directly by a code...also see my 3rd question which i just added

Comment: That is correct. You must have access to a mail server to handle your email and pass it along to the intended recipient.

Comment: plz also see my 3rd question which i just added

Comment: There is a script (phpmailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) that is full of features for sending mail.